# Restrict the type of React Component prop in Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

To achieve composition in our codebase we pass components as props. Is it possible to type check the component that is passed as a prop? As an example, I make use of a `Typography` component. This component is used in the entire codebase and is passed as a prop to many other components.

```
interface TypographyProps {
  variant:
      | 'h1'
      | 'small'
}

<Thumbnail
  name={
    <Typography variant="h4">John Doe</Typography>
  }
  secondaryLine={
    <Typography variant="small">Bakerstreet 122</Typography>
  }
/>
```

I want to restrict the properties `name` and `secondaryLine` to only receiving the `Typography` component as a prop. It would be even better to restrict the `name` prop to only receive the Typography component with this specific variant (`h4`): `<Typography variant="h4">`.

Currently I define the type like this: `name: ReactElement<typeof Typography>;`. It seems that every component can be used as a prop (not only the `Typography` component).

Is it possible to restrict the component being passed as a prop to this specific type?

Answer (score 0):

Since `variant` is a prop of `Typography`, you can specify the of `Typography.props` in the Typography implementation:

```
interface TypographyProps {
    variant: 'h1' | 'small',
    children: string | JSX.element
}

export const Typography = ({ variant, children }: TypographyProps) => (
    <div className={variant}>{ children}</div>
)
```